# The usage of future continuous

Tags: usage, future-continuous

I know that when I don't give any specific time and also it's not known for context I should say for example: I will work instead of I will be working. My question is if adding for instance 'tomorrow'is specicfic enough to use future continuous and say I will be working tomorrow

Comment: "Can you go to the park with me tomorrow?" "No - I shall be working."

Comment: In practice, people are probably more likely to say *"I **am** working tomorrow"*, where obviously if the speaker *doesn't* give any specific time (such as ***tomorrow***, there) the meaning is completely different. With a future time reference, the verb is obviously being used in "Present as Future" mode, but *without* that it would almost always be a Present tense reference to what the speaker is *currently* doing.

Answer (score 0):

- **I will work tomorrow**; *today, it’s time to play!*
- **I will be working tomorrow**, *so I won’t be able to drive you to your appointment.*

The use of a temporal modifier does not supersede the nature of the verb. In the first example *work* functions as a [bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive/) that refers to the action. The second sentence describes the actual performance of the action in the future continuous.

The author’s intent is what determines the form of the verb. Context is necessary to decide which form is most appropriate to use. Afterwards, a temporal modifier can be used to define the scope of the statement.

[More](https://promova.com/english-grammar/bare-infinitives-in-english) depth on bare infinitives.